# Should I delete my own, now-duplicate answer?

Tags: discussion

I answered my own question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507815/153578

As I mention in there, I only posted that answer since another user deleted their own, previously-posted answer which I thought was useful. That user un-deleted their answer; should I now delete mine? Are there any repercussions for my doing so?

Comment: You might delete it, but it's not mandatory. You'll loose bonus point doing so (20 as of now). Be aware that high user will still see your delete answer.

Comment: You don't deserve to lose the rep

Comment: I can imagine the two users thinking the same at the same time, and excluding the two answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please leave it, it’s useful as-is. I originally deleted my answer because I thought the others were better (since they look for numbers to extract, rather than removing characters we don’t care about — explicitly codifying what you’re looking for is often better than trying to list everything you don’t want), and then undeleted it when I saw that you thought it was useful.

(Unfortunately we don’t have a nice way of dealing with deleted content which is still deemed to be useful, apart from trying to get enough 10k+ users to vote to undelete it, but that’s hard for most <10k users to do since they don’t even see the deleted content in the first place. My “clean-up” tendencies sometimes end up being counter-productive.)

Answer (score 6):

I see no issue with your copied version of @Stephen's original answer. I'd leave yours now since it varies enough from his that it can stand on its own now. Also @Stephane edited yours which pushed it even further away from the original.